# JS Framework able to generate forms based on (django) rest api OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, rest, restful-architecture

I am using the Django REST Framework.
When using the browsable API, after clicking on the `OPTIONS` button, I see beautiful definitions of fields and allowed actions for the resource, for example this user resource below:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "name": "XSpot User Detail", 
    "description": "", 
    "renders": [
        "application/json", 
        "text/html"
    ], 
    "parses": [
        "application/json", 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "multipart/form-data"
    ], 
    "actions": {
        "PUT": {
            "url": {
                "type": "field", 
                "required": false, 
                "read_only": true
            }, 
            "mail_sent": {
                "type": "boolean", 
                "required": false, 
                "read_only": false, 
                "label": "mail sent"
            }, 
            "email": {
                "type": "email", 
                "required": true, 
                "read_only": false, 
                "label": "email address", 
                "max_length": 255
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:** are there any JS frameworks able to utilize this meta information to generate forms?

Comment: some taste of Angular... http://davidmburke.com/2014/07/06/django-rest-and-angularjs-a-dont-repeat-yourself-approach/

Comment: Oh hey thanks for linking that post. It sounds like nirvana to automatically generate forms from a rest api. I haven't seen anything that can do it. If you want to collaborate on creating a angular project to do this I'd be happy to work with you on it.

Answer (score 3):

Well i think this could be helpful http://formly-js.github.io/angular-formly this takes JSON and renders a HTML form.

Comment: Paste the core info of the link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With a few extra steps, you can have not only forms, but a complete administration based on the Django REST API. Check out ng-admin (https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin), an Angular.js module for building backend apps on top of RESTful web services.

Answer (score 0):

I started a project in order to solve this problem , PS check this [repo](https://github.com/benzid-wael/django-rest-formly), But, I recommend to generate the form configuration with the cli tool and store it in your project